# Sharing an EC2/EBS RAID10 Array using NFS

Tags: raid, amazon-web-services, nfs, software-raid, amazon-ebs

I created a 10 disks RAID10 using EBS on AWS EC2 using mdadm on a ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS instance. Let's call this instance A. It works fine and I can create files and folders perfectly in the volume.

I want to share the volume via NFS to be accessible via another instance B. So, I installed the NFS server on instance A and the NFS client on instance B and I was able to mount the RAID10 Array from A on B using NFS. I can see the files via B.

The problem is that If I try to create anything (files or folders) in the mounted volume on B, I get a permission denied even if I'm root.

Am I forgeting something?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with a normal user? According to [GNU/Linux Desktop Survival Guide](http://www.togaware.com/linux/survivor/Root_Access.html), `By default root on a client is mapped to user nobody on an NFS server`, so root user on B will have virtually no privilege on A.

Comment: That was exactly it!!! I simply added no_root_squash to the /etc/exports and all worked perfectly!! I was cracking my head for 2 days on this thing! Perfect answer. Thank you very much!